# ajax actionlink redirecting instead of updating tag

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

When I am making an ajax call the controller is redirecting and not updating my tags my code looks like as follows.

This is in the _layout.cshtml

```
<code>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript">    
    </script> 
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js")" type="text/javascript">
    </script> 
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.js")" type="text/javascript">
    </script> 
</code>
```

And This is what the web config looks like, I have also tried turning off unobtrusive javascript off with no luck.

```
<code>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
</code>
```

My controller method looks like this

```
<code>
   [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(lesson lesson)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                //Save Album 
                lesson.dateCreated = DateTime.Now;
                lesson.dateSubmitted = DateTime.Now; 
                lesson.statusID = SUBMITTED;
                lesson.submittedByUserID = getAppUserID();
                lesson.prjLessonID = createLessonPrjID(lesson.projectID);


                storeDB.lessons.InsertOnSubmit(lesson);
                storeDB.SubmitChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            // Invalid – redisplay with errors 

            else
                return View(lesson); 

        }
</code>
```

Any ideas?  Thanks in advance.

```
<code>
@if (item.statusID != null)
                {
                        <td id ="approvedmsg">@item.getLessonStatus(item.statusID.Value)</td>
                }
                else
                {
                       <td> </td>
                }

                @if (item.statusID != 3)
                {
                    <td>

                    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.lessonID }) |
                    @Ajax.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.lessonID }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "approvedmsg"})
                    </td>   
                }
</code>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try deleting `MicrosoftAjax.js` and `MicrosoftMvcAjax.js` and only use

```
<script src="<%=Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js")%>" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<%=Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")%>" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<%=Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")%>" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<%=Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")%>" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

A good post about it here http://yobriefcase.posterous.com/unobtrusive-javascript-in-mvc3

Comment: Thanks, updating the scripts solved the issue.  I had to drag and drop them from the Script file becuase, I was getting a 404 when referencing the script src .